# Rename parts of file names that match a pattern

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Say I have a list of file names like this:

```
some-file.ts  
my-project-service.ts  
other.ts  
something-my-project.ts
```

I need to change the file names that have `my-project` in them to have just that part renamed to `$appname$`.

So `my-project-service.ts` would become `$appname$-service.ts`

And I need to do this recursively from a root directory.

I seem to be to be hopeless at PowerShell so I thought I would ask here to see if anyone can help me out.

Comment: [This](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/11/22/use-powershell-to-rename-files-in-bulk/) might help you.

Comment: @MartinBrandl Thank you for the great answer!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet with the `-recurse` switch to get all items recursivly from a root directory. Filter all items containing `my-project` using the `Where-Object` cmdlet and finally rename them using the `Rename-Item` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\tmp" -Recurse | 
    Where {$_.Name -Match 'my-project'} | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace 'my-project','$appname$' }
```